# Moving to a while loop if not divisible by 5 in c++

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I am writing a program for a class where the user inputs a number that is checked to be an even number, checked to see if it is divisible by 5 and if those two are satisfied, the number is then used by a while loop. To clarify, if the number even and is divisible by 5 then code runs, if it is even and divisible by 2 then code runs. The first set of code needs to be in a for loop and the second (divisible by 2) needs to be in a while loop.

I am stuck on taking the cin and using it in the second set of code, the first set wants to manipulate it first.

Any help figuring this out would be great!

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>    
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    system ("color F0");

    int number = 0, countIf = 0,countWhile = 0, i=0;

    cout << "Please enter a positive integer or zero to quit: ";
    cin >> number;
    cin.ignore();

    if (number < 0 || number%2 != 0)
        cout << "Error: The integer entered was either not positive or a zero. Try again." << endl;

    //else if (number%5 || (number%2) = 0)

    for (number%5; countIf < number; countIf +=5)
    {
        i = number / 10;
        i += countIf;
        cout << i << " ";        
    }
    cin.ignore();

    while (countWhile <= i && i%2) 
    {
        int x = 0;
        cout << x << " ";
        x += 2;
    }

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's good practice to use brackets around the statements inside an `if` block, even if it's only one.  The original indention of the question makes me wonder whether that is also causing confusion.  **I re-edited the question to correct indentation.  There were no code changes, but you should look over the code to ensure it does what you expected it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm looking at your original else if statement

```
else if (number%5 || (number%2) = 0)
```

What you wanted here was instead

```
else if (number%5 == 0 && number%2 == 0)
```

and execute your code in that else if block.

Answer (score 0):

copy it to another variable before manipulating the data.

```
cin>>a;
b=a;
```

And use b for the second set.
And if a number is even, it is obviously divisible by 2. So you do not need to check if a number is even and if it is divisible by 2